# AngularJS $state.go no redirect with ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, express, nginx, angular-ui-router

hopefully some ran into my problem before, it's really strange. I get some weird behavior when using ExpressJS to serve my AngularApp Files locally.

I have the following statement in my main controller (wrapping the whole body):

```
else{
            console.log('Forwarding to Login');
            $state.go('signin', {});
            console.log($state.$current);
}
```

It gets actually called but nothing happens and the current state is empty.

Now the funny part: I just setup nginx locally and pointed the root path of the default configuration file to my project's root folder.. everything works.

So what can cause ExpressJS not to redirect and loading the controller when using $state.go? Using ui-sref is working...

Here my express.js config:

```
var express = require('express'); var app = express();

app.use('/libs', express.static(__dirname + '/libs')); app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets')); app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/app')); //app.use(express.errorHandler());

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname }); });

/**  * Start Server  */

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

 var host = server.address().address;  var port = server.address().port;

 console.log('X is listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

Here are my states

```
$stateProvider
        // Dashboard
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.view.html",
            data: {pageTitle: 'Home', pageSubTitle: 'MyTitle Workspace'},
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MyApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                        files: [
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
        // Login
        .state('signin', {
            url: '/signin',
            templateUrl: '/app/components/login/login.view.html',
            data: {pageTitle: 'Sign in', pageSubTitle: ''},
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'loginCtrl',
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'MyApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                        files: [
                            '/app/shared/authentication/login.controller.js'
                            ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
```

I would really appreciate any help :)

Best,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your route looks like, I recommend adding the following to your .run:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        /* Fired prior to any route change */
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        /* this will fire on EVERY successful route change */
    });

    /*
    Logs to console if a route change fails for any reason
    */
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        console.log('state change error - ' + error + ' - to: ' + angular.toJson(toState) + ' params: ' + angular.toJson(toParams) + '\nfrom: ' + angular.toJson(fromState) + ' params: ' + angular.toJson(fromParams));
    });
});
```

This will at least give you some visibility as to what is going on. You can even handle the issue directly within those blocks

Comment: Hey Incognos, thanks for the snippet, but it doesn't give me any new information. I just updated my posting and added my states file.

Comment: is $state being injected properly into the specific controller? usually throws an error if it not. When you call $state.go, is the $stateChangeStart being fired? is this running in browser? you mention Express is not doing the redirect, but I was assuming that this was an angular app with ui-router. please expand and give more details

Comment: Hey @Incogno, yeah $state is injected. As I said everything works on nginx. The strange behavior just occurs when using ExpressJS. $stateChangeStart is fired: Object {name: "$stateChangeStart", targetScope: Object, defaultPrevented: false, currentScope: Object}currentScope: nulldefaultPrevented: falsename: "$stateChangeStart"preventDefault: () {arguments: (...)get arguments: ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }set arguments: ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }caller: (...)get caller: ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }set caller: ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }length: 0name: ""

Comment: try removing the resolve and seeing if the route changes. It is possible that the lazyLoader/resolver might be interfering with your route change.

Comment: hmm.. sadly that didn't help :/ . Maybe i missed sth. in the expressJS config? I mean where is the difference between exprress and nginx in serving the files? Actually the whole routing should be done by angular and the server just needs to serve the requested files.

Comment: well, the ui-router routes($state.go) are purely angular side. I do not believe that expressjs or nginx have anything to do with it. Which is why I was focusing specifically on the angular side. Look at your developer console under the 'network' tab to make sure that all the resources are loading properly.